# Refraction Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

I have a problem that I have been working on for a long time but can't seem to get the answer.

[image: Diagram]

What thickness t of glass with an index of refraction 1.60 must be interposed between the lens and P for the image to be formed at P′, located 0.30cm to the right of P? The locations of the piece of glass and of points P and P′ are shown in the figure.

So far I have 2 equations:

(1) sin(a) = 1.6 sin(b)

(2) (t-0.3)tan(a) = (t)tan(b)

How can I solve for t? Or is there another equation I'm missing somewhere. I think it might be related with the 14.40 cm, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).